# Is it possible/practical to host an SQLite or similar relational DB in AWS S3, accessed from Lambda+api gateway for low-traffic websites?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlite, aws-lambda

I am looking for access to a relational database that is "serverless" for use in a low traffic website where the API is via lambda + api gateway.

The objective being creating an end-to-end serverless application.

I have investigated Athena - however all documentation points to avoiding it's usage as a serverless database.

Could one host an SQLite DB in S3 and interact with it via a lambda function?

Comment: Just curious, DynamoDB is serverless, and Aurora also has a serverless flavor. Why create your own db?

Comment: DynamoDB is non relational which is not suitable for my purposes. Aurora Serverless; I am unsure of the pricing and scaling mechanics of. My understanding is it cannot scale down to 0 units (costless when not in use) and I'm unsure if there is a minimum query cost, regardless of query size. If it sits idle for weeks then I have a single write, will that charge me 1 entire compute unit?

Comment: That's a good point. From https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/, it is billed per second, so it does scale to 0 units on idle. However, when it runs, there is a minimum of 0.5 compute unit (1 compute unit is what they call as having 2 GiB and corresponding CPU). At the end of the day, I guess it is dollars vs time. Major advantage is the ease of setup, maintenance, and scale to when the traffic does increase. In terms of cost, if your DB runs for 1 min a day, monthly compute cost is $0.33 (exc storage).